# Getting grouped array from JavaScript REGEX

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm currently generating a regex statement for a string comparing program I'm writing for my Discord bot. I am using the following generated regex string:

```
let regex = new RegExp("(TRIGGER WORD) (.*?)", "g");
```

I then execute it using the following:

```
let returns = regex.exec("TRIGGER WORD WHAT");
```

I get the following:

```
 [ 'stud, ', 'stud,', '', index: 0, input: 'stud, what' ]
```

Which has no indication of grouping for 'WHAT' which I am trying to get most importantly.

From a background in PHP, I am expecting that I will get an array back such as the following:

```
 ['TRIGGER WORD', 'WHAT']
```

Comment: I don't think the lazy quantifier will work there..? Use `match` instead

Comment: what are you trying to do, what is your output, did you get any error

Comment: Updated @AkhilAravind, I'm trying to get the 'what' and 'trigger word' bit  that I can access from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex, the last part `(.*?)` is lazy and will repeat the dot as few times as possible.

For your example data you could match the quantifier in the second group [greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `(.*)`. Your results are in capturing group 1 and 2.

This will match `TRIGGER WORD` in the first group, a whitespace and what is following in the second group.

```js
let regex = new RegExp("(TRIGGER WORD) (.*)", "g");
let returns = regex.exec("TRIGGER WORD WHAT");
console.log(returns);
console.log(returns[1]);
console.log(returns[2]);
```